# Large images not centering

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{
    font=normal,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{Panel \thefigure\Alph{subfigure}:}

\newcommand{\plotheight}{0.425}
\newcommand{\plotwidth}{1.45}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\plotwidth\linewidth, height=\plotheight\textheight]{monkey.jpg}
        \caption{Monkey 1}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\plotwidth\linewidth, height=\plotheight\textheight]{monkey.jpg}
        \caption{Monkey 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{2ex}
\caption{Monkey Plot}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small{This figure contains an image of the same monkey twice.}\vspace{2ex}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image: plot]

When the width of the images are less than or equal to 1, both images are centred. However, when I insert a width value larger than 1, then the images are skewed to the right, as shown in the picture.

I do get a warning from LaTeX that the images are too wide. Although, the images seems to fit perfectly fine if centred.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** the real images I am using in my report are vector based, hence they will not be distorted. But thanks to those pointing that out.

Comment: They are centered but they are larger than the text width hence they leak out to the right margin creating the illusion The problem is that your container subfigure is wasting most of the whitespace with 0.5\linewidth and images don't fit into this container

Comment: Why are you using `\plotwidth\linewidth` in the first place, where `\plotwidth` is larger than 1? Also the way you are setting height and width may distort the image, you might want to only set one of either height or width, or also add `keepaspectratio`.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you for your answer. I haven't been using the subfigure environment for too long, so I was unaware of where the problem was.

Comment: @daleif: Thank you for your comment. I guess that I was not entirely aware of how the subfigure environment works. Also, I forgot to mention that my true images are vector based, hence they will not be distorted. But thank you for pointing that out as well.

Comment: It will be distorted! Consider an image of a circle, scaled to a width of 5cm and a height of 3cm. That image is no longer a circle.

Comment: @daleif: I am sorry, you are right. They will of course be distorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE does the following:

- The subfigures are set to the fixed width of `0.5\textwidth`.
- Inside the subfigures, the included images are set to `\plotwidth\linewidth`.

Inside the subfigures, `\linewidth` equals `0.5\textwidth`. If you now set `\plotwidth` to a factor larger than one, the images will get a width that is larger than that of the subfigure. That's why you get the warning, and also centering doesn't work for overflowing stuff.

What you should do instead:

- Set the subfigures to a width `\plotwidth\textwidth` where for `\plotwidth` you can choose (and easily adjust) any number between 0 and 1.
- Inside the subfigures, set the width of the included images to the fixed `\linewidth`.

This way, you have the flexibility you wanted to have with your construction, but there will never be an overflow of the subfigure.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{
    font=normal,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{Panel \thefigure\Alph{subfigure}:}

\newcommand{\plotheight}{0.425}
\newcommand{\plotwidth}{0.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\plotwidth\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\plotheight\textheight]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Monkey 1}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{\plotwidth\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\plotheight\textheight]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Monkey 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{2ex}
\caption{Monkey Plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more comments:

- You might want to change the use of `\plotheight` in a similar way, to have a consistent scheme for both dimensions.
- You might want to reconsider setting both `width` and `height` separately, or at least to add the `keepaspectratio` option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. It solves it perfectly. To be honest, I tried to recycle some older code, where I had four images on one page. I see that their width (according to my old code) was smaller than 1, hence the reason why there were centered but the two larger images were not.

Comment: i wouldn't use `height` option. with determining only image width the original image aspect ratio is preserved.